# How to create a gulp service?

Tags: linux, node.js, service, gulp, raspbian

I am currently working on a project where the `gulpfile.js` compile dependencies but also instantiates the node JS server.

When I run the command `gulp` the tasks are performed and the server starts.

But I will wish to create a linux service to have the server that run in the background.

So I created a service:

```
USER = root
SCRIPT_DIR = 'dir location'

`NAME = gulp
DAEMON = / usr / bin / gulp
OPTIONS = "- old-max-size = 512 space-gulp --production"
LOG = 'dir location'

PIDFILE = / var / run / gulp.pid`
```

[.......]

Here is the error I get when I open the log file:

```
`[8:51:41] Using gulpfile ~ / dirName/ gulpfile.js
[8:51:41] Task 'gulp' is not in your gulpfile
[8:51:41] Please check the documentation for proper formatting gulpfile`
```

Do you have an idea of the problem please?

Best regards.

Comment: Can you share the contents of your Gulpfile?

Comment: My gulpfile is biggest !! I use the reatct admin theme : https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/rubix-reactjs-powered-admin-template-WB09498FH

Comment: Are you using absolute paths? I believe services need to use absolute paths. Also verify permissions on the file